Simulated drag event is not scrolling Scroll View correctly
I have a custom UI element that acts like a Scroll View.  In the unity emulator I can drag the element up and down and it scrolls through a list of child elements.  I want the list to have an initial scroll when the scene starts to show that it can be scrolled.  Using the below script I tried to get this auto-scrolling effect by simulating  drag event on the UI element as if I was scrolling it myself.  Instead, it immediately shifts what appears to be a bit downward, then stops.  I can't seem to find the issue.
public class AutoScroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform targetRectTransform; // The UI element (RectTransform) to simulate touch and drag on
    public float dragDistance = 200f; // Distance to simulate drag (in pixels)
    public float dragDuration = 1.0f; // Duration of the simulated drag (in seconds)

void Start()
{
    // Simulate touch and drag on the target UI element
    StartCoroutine(SimulateTouchAndDrag());
}

IEnumerator SimulateTouchAndDrag()
{
    // Create a new PointerEventData
    PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

    // Set the pointer event data position to the center of the target UI element
    pointerEventData.position = targetRectTransform.position;

    // Simulate a pointer down (touch) event
    ExecuteEvents.Execute(targetRectTransform.gameObject, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);

    // Calculate drag start and end positions
    Vector2 dragStartPosition = pointerEventData.position;
    Vector2 dragEndPosition = new Vector2(dragStartPosition.x, dragStartPosition.y + dragDistance);

    // Simulate drag movement
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    while (elapsedTime < dragDuration)
    {
        float t = elapsedTime / dragDuration;
        Vector2 currentPosition = Vector2.Lerp(dragStartPosition, dragEndPosition, t);

        // Update pointer event data position
        pointerEventData.position = currentPosition;

        // Simulate drag handler on the target UI element
        ExecuteEvents.Execute(targetRectTransform.gameObject, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);

        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    // Simulate a pointer up (release) event
    ExecuteEvents.Execute(targetRectTransform.gameObject, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
}
}

